# Failed to find sync for id=0 flutter 3.7.5

Tags: flutter, dart

Compiler allocated 4533KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
E/SurfaceSyncer( 5850): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  ( 5850): Expecting binder but got null!

flutter clean and update the latest version of flutter

Comment: Please provide more information. You can refer to the official flutter github issues - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116669